# Sabre Soap API saving error

Tags: xml, soap, sabre

I am trying to save a PNR but I am getting the error below. Does anyone know if there is a way to fix or override the error through the API so that it can be saved?

===================== Request XML: =====================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <SOAP-ENV:Header>
                <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0">
                    <eb:From>
                        <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">from</eb:PartyId>
                    </eb:From>
                    <eb:To>
                        <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">ws</eb:PartyId>
                    </eb:To>
                    <eb:CPAId>IPCC</eb:CPAId>
                    <eb:ConversationId>testing123</eb:ConversationId>
                    <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML"></eb:Service>
                    <eb:Action>EndTransactionLLSRQ</eb:Action>
                </eb:MessageHeader> 
                <ns6:Security xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0">
                    <ns6:BinarySecurityToken>Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/RESB!ICESMSLB\/RES.LB!-3125948********!0</ns6:BinarySecurityToken>
                </ns6:Security>
            </SOAP-ENV:Header>
            <SOAP-ENV:Body> 
            <EndTransactionRQ Version="2.0.8" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <EndTransaction Ind="true" />
                    <Source ReceivedFrom="OTH" />
            </EndTransactionRQ>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
===================== Response XML: =====================

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap-env:Header><eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1"><eb:From><eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">ws</eb:PartyId></eb:From><eb:To><eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">from</eb:PartyId></eb:To><eb:CPAId>IPCC</eb:CPAId><eb:ConversationId>testing123</eb:ConversationId><eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML"/><eb:Action>EndTransactionLLSRS</eb:Action><eb:MessageData><eb:MessageId>9133913861458500202</eb:MessageId><eb:Timestamp>2018-07-12T23:55:45</eb:Timestamp></eb:MessageData></eb:MessageHeader><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/RESB!ICESMSLB\/RES.LB!-3125948754382560628!964441!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken></wsse:Security></soap-env:Header><soap-env:Body><EndTransactionRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.0.8">
 <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
  <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2018-07-12T18:55:45-05:00">
   <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
    <stl:Message>VERIFY ORDER OF ITINERARY SEGMENTS - MODIFY OR END TRANSACTION</stl:Message>
    <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
   </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
  </stl:Error>
 </stl:ApplicationResults>
</EndTransactionRS></soap-env:Body></soap-env:Envelope>:
====================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this - its most likely because you try to save an open jaw (e.g. FRA-SFO - DEN-FRA) or something similar.

There are several solutions to this problem - i ranked them in order of best practices.

Best practice would be to put in a land segment (ARUNK) in these cases. https://richmedia.sabre.com/docs/pdfs/pnr6.pdf

Otherwise its possible to change/turn off this warning/validation through the TJR settings via the GUI.

Last but not least you could try to send the End Transaction Request and it should create the PNR.

Comment: I send an "end transaction request" with every request do I need to send it again? how would I go about it? Also, can you elaborate on how I can input an ARUNK in SWS?

Comment: "Otherwise its possible to change/turn off this warning/validation through the TJR settings via the GUI." I was unable to figure out how to turn off the warnings do you know the command for it?

Comment: Re Arunk: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Add_Arrival_Unknown_Segment . You need to do this before ending the transaction if you use the orchestrated workflow and then call end the transaction. So workflow will be enhanched airbook -> passenger details (ignore after false) -> add arunk -> end transaction

Comment: Re: end transaction. If you use it with the orchestrated airbook you need to call the end transaction again with the end transaction call. Make sure that ignore after=false on the orchestrated airbook workflow

Comment: Re: turning the validation off. I dont know - our ticketing agency did this for us. If in doubt contact your sabre account manager regarding this